# Computation of classes of vector bundles over spheres

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, vector-bundles, characteristic-classes

I am trying to compute the number of classes of real vector bundles over spheres. I am reading Bott Tu (Differential Forms in Algebraic Topology) and have worked out using Bott Periodicity Theorem the following table (which I upload as a picture cause I was not able to make the code work here):

[image]

Now, using standard stufff from Bott Tu, to be precise: 
$$\text{Vect}_k(\mathbb{S}^q) \simeq \pi_{q-1}(O(k))/\mathbb{Z}_2.$$

I obtain that the number of classes of real vector bundles over the sphere $\mathbb{S}^q$ are:

[image]

I even guess the following, but I am not sure:

[image]

Are my results correct? Is there any reference where I can check them?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's been a long time since I learned (hah!) any of this stuff, but is it possible that this is a classification of *orientable* vector bundles rather than all vector bundles?

Comment: I think that the problem (or at least one of them) is that I dind't shift the index by one in order to construct the second table. I mean, I used $$\text{Vect}_k(\mathbb{S}^q) \simeq \pi_{q}(O(k))/\mathbb{Z}_2$$ instead of
 $$\text{Vect}_k(\mathbb{S}^q) \simeq \pi_{q-1}(O(k))/\mathbb{Z}_2$$

But thanks for answering so quickly!

Comment: Why do you quotient by $Z_2$? Moreover how is $Z_2$ a subgroup of $Z$?

Comment: You are right @user17786 , I should explain where this comes from. It is not a quotient as a subgroup, but the quotient of an action. It is explained in Bott Tu, I just ask if there was anyone who was aware of the classification and could check it. Anyway, I will edit the question due to your smart comment. Thanks!

Comment: It is you who is right. Then one more comment: the only action of $Z_2$ on $Z_2$ is the identity, so you are not killing anything in those cases.

Comment: You are right again @user17786 . I suspect that maybe I am not understanding $\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{Z}_2$ and $\mathbb{Z}_2/\mathbb{Z}_2$  appropriately.  I will think abut it again more carefully. Thanks again!

Comment: Wait, I think that I am killing everything in the case $\mathbb{Z}_2/\mathbb{Z}_2$ since the action is transitive.

Comment: No, the action of $Z_2$ on $Z_2$ is by the identity, which fixes every element.